# How to get data from [object,Object ] Js

Tags: javascript, arraylist, base64

I am trying to encode data(using `btoa()` )  send it to a data-base then when i retrieve it and decode it i am unable to access the content
i just get an array of [object , Object ]

```
data = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],....

output of : JSON.parse(data) =  [object Object]
output of : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) = "[object,Object]"
output of : data[0] = [ 
output of : actual.hasOwnProperty("key") = false 
i tried : x = `[${data}]` same problem it only read the data object as a string
```

Comment: You can't get data from `[object: Object]` because it's just a string. You incorrectly saved the data into the database.

Comment: the data is saved as 64 base string

Comment: It appears that it's not

Answer (score 1):

so actually i was encoding a js object
adding :`data = JSON.stringify(data).toString();`
solved the problem

Comment: `JSON.stringify` already returns a string, you don't have to use `toString` then.

Comment: for a reason if i don't use toString() i get the [object,Object] as response